# sqldeveloper ORA-12505. TNS: listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor, and restart oracleSersvice XE not working for me

Tags: oracle, connectivity

I have been confused for a few days; I tried many ways but they did not work.
Here are my `tnsnames.ora` and `listener.ora`. please help me out.

`tnsnames.ora`:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\zilon\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LAPTOP-BH64CB9N.lan)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LAPTOP-BH64CB9N.lan))(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

`listener.ora`:

```
    # listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\zilon\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\zilon\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\zilon\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LAPTOP-BH64CB9N.lan)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

```
lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 06-DEC-2021 14:30:18

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=LAPTOP-BH64CB9N.lan)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                06-DEC-2021 14:30:13
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 8 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\zilon\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\zilon\product\18.0.0\diag\tnslsnr\LAPTOP-BH64CB9N\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=LAPTOP-BH64CB9N)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

[image]

```
SQL> shutdown
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1610610664 bytes
Fixed Size                  9029608 bytes
Variable Size             788529152 bytes
Database Buffers          805306368 bytes
Redo Buffers                7745536 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
```

new update listener status that deletes listener.ora

```
lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 06-DEC-2021 16:52:59

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                06-DEC-2021 16:44:47
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 8 min. 12 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         C:\app\zilon\product\18.0.0\diag\tnslsnr\LAPTOP-BH64CB9N\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=LAPTOP-BH64CB9N)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

```
Enter user-name: / AS SYSDBA

Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0

SQL> show parameter local_listener

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
local_listener                       string      LISTENER_XE
SQL> alter system register
  2 
System altered.
```

```
add this line (SID_DESC = (GLOBAL_DBNAME = XE) (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\zilon\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE) (SID_NAME = XE) ) one listener file 
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\zilon\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\zilon\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\zilon\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
     (SID_DESC = (GLOBAL_DBNAME = XE) (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\zilon\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE) (SID_NAME = XE) )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LAPTOP-BH64CB9N.lan)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Comment: What does MySQL have to do with this?

Comment: show us the output of 'lsnrctl status'.  Copy and paste the full command _and_ the full output, not a screen shot.  Also, since this is sqldeveloper, show us a screen shot of the 'properies' page for your connection.

Comment: @EdStevens I have update the lsnrctl status and the connection properies, thank you so much to help me !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I don't know where that list of "properties" came from.  It's certainly not the screen shot of the SQL Dev 'properties' page for your XE connection, as I asked for. I asked for this because your subject line referenced SQL DEv.   Your lsnrctl status shows no databases registered with it, as would be expected from the reported error.  I'd first delete (rename) your listener.ora, then restart the listener.  The listener will quite happily start with all default values, which is all you need.  After that, make sure your db is started.  Re-check the listener status  (Continued ....)

Comment: (... Continued)  and make sure the database is listed as a known service/instance.

Comment: @EdStevens update the lsnrctl status and add the connection properties of XE connection page, hope it works. I would appreciate your help !!!!

Comment: and I have tried to delete listener.ora and restart listener service then create the listener.ora and restart service again.

Comment: Don't recreate the listener.ora at all.  Let the listener run without out it. You don't need it. Without that file, the listener will run with all default values, and that's all you need. You aren't anywhere near the point that you need to do anything other than defaults for the listener. Also, Your listener status indicates that the database is not started.  Start it.  It should register itself with the listener, and that will be reflected in the next check of the listener status. When we see that, we will know how to set the properties in sqldev.

Comment: @EdStevens I shut down the database using SQL command and start it (show above) without listener.ora, and update the listener status. but it still 12505 error. thank you!!!!!

Comment: It appears that your instance is not registering itself with the listener.  Use sqlplus to connect 'as sysdba', just like when you started the db. Then issue the command 'show parameter local_listener', and 'alter system register'.  Copy and paste the session.

Comment: @EdStevens updated the content on the bottom. thank you!

Comment: and by the way, I have used net configuration assistent to add a listener to deal with the problem. but it not work

Comment: _"I have used net configuration assistent to add a listener"_  I can't narrow down the problem if you keep moving the goalposts.  Delete the listener.ora.  Leave it deleted.  OK, LOCAL_LISTENER=LISTENER_XE.  That is referencing an entry in your tnsnames.ora file.  We need to see that entry.   Your 'alter system' command needs a semicolon to terminate it.

Comment: @EdStevens already deleted listener. ora when I use SQL command and used a semicolon to terminate command

Comment: Again ... OK, LOCAL_LISTENER=LISTENER_XE. That is referencing an entry in your tnsnames.ora file. We need to see that entry.

Comment: @EdStevens I solevd it !!!!!!!!, I add this line on the listener.ora file

Comment: (SID_DESC = (GLOBAL_DBNAME = XE) (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\zilon\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE) (SID_NAME = XE) )

Comment: it is under SID_LIST_LISTENER =. also update the whole file code at the bottom.  Wowwowowowowowowowowoowowwowowo. so happy. and thank you spent so much time on me !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I don't know how this works, but it works !!!!

Comment: It works because you created a static registration of the database.  I was trying to direct you to get to a dynamic registration, which would work if everything were left at defaults.  The fact that you got it to work (only) with a static registration means that the dynamic registration mechanism is not working.  That's why I wanted to see the tnsnames.ora file, as that is the next link in the chain for dynamic registration.